# Displaying 3D graphs using JUNG

Tags: jung, java-3d

I am new to JUNG, I can display graphs in 2D but can anyone show me how to show 3d graphs.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with JUNG from what I know. However you could use something like [UbiGraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/) which has language bindings for Java so you would be able to communicate with it from a JUNG application.

Comment: JUNG 2.0 probably can see [http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jung/wiki/JUNG2Basics] and [http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization3d/package-summary.html].  Unfortunately I don't know how either, sorry Ali.